# Как вывести информацию из массива $_POST в другом файле?

Tags: php, массивы, файлы

Всем привет. Вчера задавал подобный вопрос по поводу массива $_SESSION, и теперь возникла такая же проблема с массивом $_POST. Вот ниже пример кода, в котором в массив $_SESSION идёт отправка данных с форм. Так вот, этот пример из файла save_user.php. Как мне вывести значение ключа 'data' в другом файле?  print_r($_POST['data']) не работает, пробовал(echo тоже не помогает). Подключал сессии в этих двух файлах - тоже не выводит информацию о ключе. Или может это вообще не с помощью сессий решается? Не кидайтесь камнями и помидорами, если считаете вопрос глупым, просто хочу сделать личный кабинет на сайте.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
            $login = $_POST['login'];  
            $password = $_POST['password']; 
            $data = $_POST['data'];     
            $city = $_POST['city'];         
        }
```

Comment: Что значить передать в файл? Если файл находится и исполняется как часть всего приложения то никак не надо передавать т.к данные уже в общедоступном месте в переменной SESSION или POST. А если он отдельно - тогда посредством сохранения данных в файл, БД или через консольные параметры.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov В файле 1 есть значение переменной в массиве $_POST. Как мне вывести это значение в файле 2? Может, так вам будет проще меня понять

Comment: @SnoopyDoggyDog, вам нужно понять что такое суперглобальные переменные и контекст исполнения приложения. POST не ограничен как обычные переменные файлом/функцией/классом, если вы включаете через include/require другой файл то он будет доступен и там как следствие одного и того же контекста. Поэтому я и уточнял если другой файл находится в контексте другого приложения. Если у него есть доступ к сессии то на здоровье, пользуйтесь ей вместо POST и передавайте значения через переменную сессии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_POST` это суперглобальный массив который отдает нам сервер, в нем хранятся данные из `POST` запроса на сервер на этот файл, эти данные будут ограничены только для одного файла. Передать между файлами и запросами их можно с помощью тех же сессий, пример.

**file_one.php**

```
$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST;
```

**file.php**

```
echo $_SESSION['data']['name']
```

Ну или же вы можете подключить к файлу где доступен массив `$_POST`, файл, где он понадобиться.

Comment: То есть, в условии, в массив $_POST записать значение переменной data(которая находится в массиве S_SESSION)?
А потом в другом файле сделать 
print_r($_SESSION['data']);?

Comment: То есть там где вам надо в массив `$_SESSION` Занести массив `$_POST` И потом работать с ним так где вам нужно.

Comment: Я создал отдельное условие if(isset($_SESSION['submit'])){$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];} и в другом файле делаю вывод print_r ($_SESSION['data']); Ход моих мыслей правильный или нет?

Comment: Вот верное `if($_POST['sumbit']) { $_SESSION['data'] = $_POST; }` теперь в любом файле где доступные сеессии по сути в ячейке `data` Будет доступен массив `$_POST`.

Comment: Сделал так как вы написали - не работает :( в переменную $data нужно записать значение, которое равно значению ключа data в массиве $_SESSION(которое равно $_POST)

Comment: Вобщем, провозившись полчаса с массивами сделал так, как и хотел. Наговнокодить пришлось конечно знатно, но щас буду исправлять. Спасибо Вам за ответ, хоть он и косвенно решил мою проблему

Comment: Всегда рад, пометьте пожалуйста ответ, как удовлетворяющий вас, чтобы другие пользователи смогли сореинтироватся.